# Download xlsx file (or any formats that cannot be read by notepad) from Google Storage and store it locally

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, fs

I currently have a node.js server running where I can grab a **csv** file stored in storage bucket and store that to a local file.

However, when I try to do the same thing with a **xlsx** file, it seems to mess up the file and cannot be read when I download it to a local directory.

**Here is my code for getting the file to a stream:**

```
async function getFileFromBucket(fileName) {
    var fileTemp = await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName);
    return await fileTemp.download()
}
```

and with the data returned from above code, I store it into local directory by doing the following:

`fs.promises.writeFile('local_directory', DataFromAboveCode)`

It seems to work fine with **.csv** file but does not work with **.xlsx** file where I can open the csv file but xlsx file gets corrupted and cannot be opened.

I tried downloading the xlsx file directly from the storage bucket on google cloud console but it seems to work fine, meaning that somethings gone wrong in the downloading / saving process

Could someone guide me to what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: Couple of questions: (1) Can you check what is the content type of the downloaded response? (2) Is the file size the same once it is downloaded?

Comment: Can you share the metadata of your blob?